# Regular expression match array of words excluding words found in contractions

Tags: javascript, regex

Say I have an array of words, for example: (hi|ll|this|that|etc) and I want to find it in the following text:

> **Hi**, I'**ll** match **this** and **ll** too

I'm using: `\\b(hi|ll|this|that|etc)\\b`

But I want to only match whole words, excluding words found in contractions. Basically treat apostrophes as another "word seperator". In this case, it shouldn't match the "ll" in "I'll".

Ideas?

Comment: Maybe `(?:[^']|^)(hi|ll|this|that|etc)\b`: _https://regex101.com/r/gD7aC0/1_

Answer (score 3):

Use the apostrophe in addition to `\b` to begin and end a match:

```
(?:\b|')(hi|ll|this|that|etc)(?:\b|')
```

`(?:...)` means a non-capturing group. [Stub on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/xD6oJ5/1)

Answer (score 3):

If you want match just words you can try with:

```
(?:^|(?=[^']).\b)(hi|ll|th(?:is|at)|etc)\b
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/gD7aC0/3)

and get words with group 1. However the `\b` will still allow to match fragments like: `-this` or `@ll`. I don't know is it desired result.