# How can hide storybook control per story arg

Tags: storybook

I have rails engine project using storybook and mdx files to specify the controls
but i need to hide specific control per story

```
<Meta
    title='Label Component'
    story='with_tooltip'
    args={{
        object: 'employee',
        field_name: 'name',
        text: 'Employee name',
        tooltip: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing eli'
    }}
/>
```

I have two stories [label,with_tooltip]

in case label story i need to hide tooltip control
I'm using view component preview to show components

Answer (score 34):

You can disable controls for individual properties of a story including the prop table documentation, or you can disable only the control and leave the prop table documentation intact.

To disable the control and prop table documentation for the `tooltip` prop:

```js
<Meta
    title='Label Component'
    story='with_tooltip'
    args={{
        object: 'employee',
        field_name: 'name',
        text: 'Employee name',
        tooltip: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing eli'
    }}
    argTypes={{
      tooltip: {
        table: {
          disable: true
        }
      }
    }}

/>
```

To disable the control but leave the prop table documentation intact for the `tooltip` prop:

```js
<Meta
    title='Label Component'
    story='with_tooltip'
    args={{
        object: 'employee',
        field_name: 'name',
        text: 'Employee name',
        tooltip: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing eli'
    }}
    argTypes={{
      tooltip: {
        control: false
      }
    }}

/>
```

See the [Storybook docs on disabling controls for specific properties](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/essentials/controls#disable-controls-for-specific-properties).

Answer (score 12):

The best approach is doing this:

```
export default {
  title: 'Pages/Login ',
  component: Login,
  parameters:{
    controls:{
        exclude:/.*/g
    }
  }
} as ComponentMeta<typeof Login>;
```

Answer (score 3):

For someone searching for a way to remove the control and change the control count, use amir's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73625190/10992558):

```json
parameters:{
    controls:{
       
        exclude:/.*/g
    }
}
```

**But** changing the regex `'/.*/g'`(used to remove all the controls) for either:

- Another regex that works for you.
- A string with the name of the control you want to disable.
- The following regex, changing the passing the names of the controls you want to disable between pipes(`|`).
  `(?:\b|')(string1|string2|string3)(?:\b|')`
  For anyone that wants the explanation for the regex, you can read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33404991/10992558) comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exclude` to remove or hide a specific argument in the story :

```
export default {
  title: 'Pages/Login ',
  component: Login,
  parameters:{
    controls:{
        exclude: ["tooltip"]
    }
  }
} as ComponentMeta<typeof Login>;
```

Read more at [Documentation](https://storybook.js.org/docs/essentials/controls#filtering-controls)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the Rails environment, but perhaps it is like this.

```
<Meta
    ...
    argTypes={{
        tooltip: { control: { type: false } }
    }}
/>
```

---

For React,
the latest writing style probably looks like this.

```
const meta = Meta<typeof Label> = {
    ...
    argTypes: {
        tooltip: { control: { type: false } }
    },
}
```

If `tooltip: { control: false }` is set, it show setup page link.